# Python : Grid projection issue between 4326 and 3857

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj

I have a polygon in epsg:4326 coords and I would like to create a regular grid of 7000 meters mesh size.

```
import numpy as np
import shapely
import pyproj
import geopandas as gpd

polygon_aoi = polygon_aoi = shapely.geometry.Point([-20, 20]).buffer(0.5) # coords in 4326
stepsize = 7000 # 7 km grid step size
```

The first step is to convert in epsg:3857 my polygon.

```
to_meters_transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs('epsg:4326', 'epsg:3857')
degres_coords_edges_x, degres_coords_edges_y = np.squeeze(polygon_aoi.exterior.coords.xy)
# dont know why i have to reverse y and x in the output here
meters_coords_edges_y, meters_coords_edges_x = to_meters_transformer.transform(degres_coords_edges_x, 
                                                                               degres_coords_edges_y)
```

Then I'm doing the grid using a meshgrid

```
x_start, x_stop = np.min(meters_coords_edges_x) - stepsize, np.max(meters_coords_edges_x) + stepsize
y_start, y_stop = np.min(meters_coords_edges_y) - stepsize, np.max(meters_coords_edges_y) + stepsize
x_range, y_range = np.arange(x_start, x_stop, stepsize), np.arange(y_start, y_stop, stepsize)
x_points_meters, y_points_meters = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
coords_final = np.stack([x_points_meters, y_points_meters]).transpose(1,2,0)
```

And then I create 2 gdf, one in meters and the other one in degrees

```
list_polygon = []
len_x, len_y, _ = coords_final.shape
# defining mesh one by one
for x_index in range(len_x - 1):
    for y_index in range(len_y - 1):
        p1 = coords_final[x_index, y_index, :]
        p2 = coords_final[x_index, y_index+1, :]
        p3 = coords_final[x_index+1, y_index+1, :]
        p4 = coords_final[x_index+1, y_index, :]
        p = shapely.geometry.Polygon([p1, p2, p3, p4])
        list_polygon.append(p)
        
gdf_grid_meters = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : list_polygon}, index = range(len(list_polygon)), crs = 'epsg:3857')
gdf_grid_degres = gdf_grid_meters.to_crs('epsg:4326')
```

But when I am plotting the gdf, the meters seems to be valid but the other one (which is only a reprojection) is not valid.

first plot in meters :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(meters_coords_edges_x, meters_coords_edges_y)
gdf_grid_meters.plot(facecolor = 'none', ax = ax)
ax.axis('equal')
```

[image]

second plot in degrees :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(degres_coords_edges_x, degres_coords_edges_y)
gdf_grid_degres.plot(facecolor = 'none', ax = ax)
ax.axis('equal')
```

[image]

Whatever the input polygon I'm using the issue still exist, I'm feeling like there is something I don't understand. What is it?

Comment: It is not possible to generate a Cartesian grid in either WGS1984 decimal degrees **or** Web Mercator. 4326 because each step north or south changes the distance along east-west, and 3857 because distance is meaningless in Web Mercator (the poles are infinitely far from the Equator).

Comment: I understand the problem for a epsg3857 projection but in 4326 the coordinates are evolving on a sphere. So there should be no problem. How could i do in your opinion ? So in my case i could do a grid bu the closest the polygon is from the poles, the more the grid is distorted on the latitude coords ?

Comment: No, 4326 is a spheroid, and a grid of equidistant orthogonal lines is not possible across that surface. The closest you can come is equal *area*  cells with fixed width and variable height (for which you would need geodesic functions to iteratively calculate the area of the spheroidal trapezoids to home in on the right height).

Comment: I will do this so. Thank you for your answer.